# Como tomar la id del usuario logueado para llevarlo a una nueva tabla

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo 3 tablas mysql: "users", "torneos", e "inscritos", "inscritos" solo posee 2 foreign key (idUser e idTorneo) y una tabla html que me muestra el listado de "torneos"

Lo que busco es que el usuario se pueda registrar en un torneo presionando un botón dentro de la tabla html (tomar la id del usuario logueado JUNTO con la id del torneo seleccionado y llevar ambos valores a la tabla "inscritos" (la cual utilizo para checkear cupos).

El botón dentro de mi tabla es el siguiente (torneos.php):

```
<td>
    <form method="post" action="torneos.php">
        <input type="text" name="idTorneo" value="<?php echo $row['idTorneo']; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="idUser" value="<?php echo $row['idUser']; ?>">
        <button class="inscribirse" type="submit" name="inscribir"></button>
    </form>
</td>
```

Los inputs estan visibles para que yo pueda comprobar que se están tomando ambos ID (user y torneo) pero solo arroja el id del torneo mientras que en el id de usuario me dice que la variable no esta definida en la línea `<?php echo $row['idUser']; ?>`

La función que quiero que se ejecute al presionar el botón es:

```
session_start();
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'wwr_users');
$idUser = 0;
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors   = array(); 
if (isset($_POST['inscribir'])) {
    $idTorneo = $_POST['idTorneo'];
    $idUser = $_POST['idUser'];
    mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `inscritos`(`idTorneo`, `idUser`) VALUES ('$idTorneo', '$idUser')");
    header('location: torneos.php');
}
```

La query funciona de maravilla insertándose manualmente en phpmyadmin, el resto de la funcionalidad no lo sé debido a que no pasa nada al apretar el botón por falta de la idUser.

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, gracias.

Comment: Si lo que buscas es que el usuario **logeado** se una al torneo, porque no declaras una variable de sesión que contenga el id del usuario que se loguea, de esta forma al momento de querer registrar al usuario en el torneo que eligió podrías usar `$_session['idusuario']`

Comment: @Arreguin92 Porque el session id me da un valor diferente al id de usuario en la base de datos, necesito el id de la base de datos.

Comment: @Lyonknows, prueba a crearte la variable de Session del Id de la BBDD ademas de la sesion que ya tienes, o bien hacer un select antes del insert para obtener el id que buscas

Answer (score 1):

Debes estar errando en la asignación del valor que le intentas dar a $idUser, ya que en el formulario parece todo estar en orden

Podrías mostrar las líneas anteriores al formulario.

Comment: Las lineas anteriores a ese formulario corresponden a una tabla html que hace echo a los valores de la tabla ‘torneo’ en la bdd, el unico echo que pude definir hasta ahora me muestra solo el primer id de la tabla ‘users’ en vez del id del usuario logueado.

Comment: apreciado amigo, me refiero a las líneas anteriores a ese formulario, ya que una de esas lineas asigna el valor de idTorneo, y de idUser. La variable idUser tiene un error